# Can't pass validation with require_from_group method - jQuery Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, rules, required

My imported **scripts**:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

My **form**:

```
    <input name="tel"    type="text"  class="form-control contact" >
    <input name="mobile" type="text"  class="form-control contact" >
    <input name="email"  type="email" class="form-control contact" >
```

My validation  **rules**:

```
    $('#new-contact-form').validate({

        rules: {
            name:   { required: true },
            title:  { required: true }, 
            mobile: { require_from_group: [1, '.contact'] },
            tel:    { require_from_group: [1, '.contact'] },
            email:  { require_from_group: [1, '.contact'] },
        }   

    });
```

When validator validates form inputs Im getting error message for each input: `Please fill at least 1 of these fields` even if I have one or more inputs filled. Did I missed something?

Comment: Works fine here after I replaced your CDN-sourced jquery.validate.min.js with a fresh download from jqueryvalidation.org. The CDN version gave me a TypeError: g.elementValue is not a function. Your JS has an excess comma after email, but that likely just comes from your deleting the rest of the rules and in any case not an explanation for the validation failure.

Comment: Originally I had spelling mistake in .contact class until I fixed it. Then the error you're talking about appeared, so you're rigth,